# Slide up from bottom with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown menu which animates the dropdown by increasing height, however it goes from the top to the bottom. Is it possible to go from the bottom to the top?

Here's my code:

```
animate({height:'show',opacity:'show'}, ddsmoothmenu.transition.overtime)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the ul that gets animated to `position: relative` (or absolute) and `bottom: 0px` (or whatever px works best). Also remove `top: -88px`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a solution to this is to absolutely position the element `bottom`. So just wrap it in a `position: relative` element and then use bottom: to get it to show up where you want it to go.